# AnyLogic - using Functions refering to DES agents variables

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling a DES process and I need to have a repetitive code at the "On Enter" of many blocks. So the code looks something like that:

```
if(agent.batchSize > 1999)
agent.priority = 100;

else if(agent.batchSize > 999)
agent.priority = 80;
```

Now since this is repetitive, I would like to have it changed once and not in every block. So I thought I could use a function. But the function will not understand the "agent." syntax since it is outside the DES block.

How can this be addressed?

Many thanks,

Emile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function with an argument "agent" of the type that your agents actually are. If you did not give them a specific agent type, just define the type as `Agent` as below:
[image]

Please also study more example models and the help as this is a core functionality of AnyLogic and programming in general :)

Comment: Not all AnyLogic users are programming experts... So sometimes a little support is needed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries. But I hope it is helpful to get a feeling for what is very obscure advanced stuff (not worth knowing) and what is very basic core functionality :-) Glad I could help. Brevity here on SOF is mostly caused by lack of time ;)